# Style sheet in ASP not working in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I have code in classic asp with css style, and I want to input that same coding in asp.net using VB. When I try it, it just continuously runs the loop. Thanks for your help.

```
            <%
            dim img
            img = "baby.jpg"
            %>
            <div class="classname"> <img src="<%response.write baby%>"> </div> 
            <%dim imgPIX
            imgPIX = 60 
            %>
            <style>
            .icons { display: block; width: <%response.write imgPIX%>px; height: <%response.write imgPIX%>px; background-image: url(<%response.write img%>); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
            <%
            dim ico_number,col
            dim row_number,rw

                           //THIS ONE HERE
            for row_number = 1 to 7
             rw = (row_number - 1) * (-1 * imgPIX) 
                for ico_number = 1 to 7
                    col = (ico_number - 1) *(-1 * imgPIX)
                    response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: "& col &"px "& rw &"px; } "

                    'response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: 0px 0px; } "
                next
            next 
            %>
            </style>

            <center>
            <table>
            <%for row_number = 1 to 7%>
            <tr>
            <%for ico_number = 1 to 7%>
            <td><span class="icons icon<%response.write row_number%>_<%response.write ico_number%>" style="float:left;"></span></td>
            <%
            next%>
            </tr>
            <%next
            %>
            </table>
```

Comment: which loop is running continuously?

Comment: @Shredder this loop " for row_number = 1 to 7"

Comment: What makes you think it is running an infinite loop?

Comment: Also I see 2 "for row_number = 1 to 7" loops. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @Shredder sorry for the late reply, because the page is forever loading. Should there be any changes I should make when putting a stylesheet from asp classic to asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a stylesheet, but an .aspx or .asp page. I didn't take the time to test your different styles generated by this code, but I ran it and it is definitely not doing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with your style sheets, in most situations a stylesheet is only going to apply the look to a page it's not going to affect the load time.  If this is the for loop that is running forever:

```
for row_number = 1 to 7
  rw = (row_number - 1) * (-1 * imgPIX) 
  for ico_number = 1 to 7
     col = (ico_number - 1) *(-1 * imgPIX)
     response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: "& col &"px "& rw &"px; } "

     'response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: 0px 0px; } "
   next
next
```

Your row_number is never being incremented as far as I can tell.  Unless I'm not following the code completely?